# Connect Rsyslog to Kafka by Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have two configuration files to use them to make a stream from rsyslog to a Kafka topic, configurations are as follows:
worker.propertiese

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins
```

syslog.propertiese

```
name=syslog-source
tasks.max=3
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.syslog.SyslogSourceConnector
syslog.port=514
syslog.listener=TCP
syslog.listen.address=0.0.0.0
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
#confluent.topic.replication.factor=1
topics=rsyslog
```

But it doesn't write logs to Kafak. The output is as follows:

```
[2020-03-07 07:23:21,698] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=syslog-source-0} Source task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:209)
[2020-03-07 07:23:31,046] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=syslog-source-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:416)
[2020-03-07 07:23:31,048] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=syslog-source-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:433)
```

Can anyone help me to know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

After many trying, i found out it's better to install `rsyslog-kafka` package, cause `rsyslog` supports Kafka natively.

```
sudo apt install rsyslog-kafka
```